# error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined`

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex

eerror: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined`

```
 actions: {
        async register({ dispatch }, form) {

          //sign up user
          const { user } = await fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.email, form.password)
    
          // create user profile object

          await fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).set({
            name: form.name
          })
    
          //fetch user profile
          
          dispatch('fetchUserProfile', user)
    
        },
```

help find the problem pls Where a can define doc ? Or where is mistake ?

Comment: That’s because `fb.usersCollection` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error

```
 Cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined
```

check your value before the dot ".XXX" eg.

```
fb.usersCollection.doc
console.log(fb.usersCollection) // undefined
```

Your `fb.usersCollection` has an "undefined" value because `fb` doesn't contain any `usersCollection`. If you wanna access your firebase "users" collection you have to do

```
fb.collection('users').doc(...);
```

checkout [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) documentation

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
import { fb, db } from '@/modules/firebase'
...
await db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
        name: form.name
      })
```